# Unable to parse '' as integer [ForceClose]

Tags: android

I have this code to retrieve data from file then make some treatment, and finally set the result in an EditTextPreference.

```
 try {
                //open the specified input file and create a reader
                FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(fileDir+fileName);
                InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(ipsr);


                String ligne;

                while ((ligne = b.readLine()) != null) {
                    String prix = ligne.split(" ")[2];
                    //prix = prix.substring(0, prix.length() - 2);
                    Log.d("PRIX",prix);
                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    String prix_total = settings.getString("prix_total", "0");
                        int a= Integer.valueOf(prix_total);
                     int c= Integer.valueOf(prix);
                 a= c + a;
                  String z=String.valueOf(a);
                  Log.d("A",z);

                  EditTextPreference myEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prix_total");
                  myEditTextPreference.setText(z); 
}


            //done, cleanup and return
            fIn.close();
            ipsr.close();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("blah", "Exception", e);
        }
```

However, i'm encountering this problem(logcat):

```
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866): Exception
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at carburant.android.com.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:46)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-12 01:09:10.941: ERROR/blah(10866):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be the problem? I debugged "prix" and founding that it outputs `''` :.
Thanks for helping.
PS: The data has that form:

```
data = date + ": " + y + "L/100KM "+ " " + value1 + "dt "+ value2 + "KM\n";
```

Comment: Here it is :-  "L/100KM "+ " " + ,  when you split (" ") the array[2] will be '', remove space inside "L/100KM" or remove + " " or change String prix = ligne.split(" ")[2];  into String prix = ligne.split(" ")[3];

Comment: @Sudar Nimalan: You can answer me, correct answer ;). (I found it before you wrote me, stupid error :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valueOf and parseInt can't handle empty strings or nulls.  Add some checks such as using TextUtils.IsEmpty(string) to verify you are not passing empty data.

Also I see you are surrounding this with a try block, consider adding a catch (NumberFormatException ex) block and logging the error if it is never supposed to be empty.